# Connect to AXIS 1.4 Webservice through a proxy

Tags: web-services, axis, webservices-client

I am using AXIS 1.4 to generate the subs for my webservice. The generation works fine as it is, but I am facing a problem to connect to the webservice though a WebProxy.

I use the axistools-maven-plugin to generate my axis classes.

```
   <plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>axistools-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.4</version>
<configuration>
 <urls>
  <url>http://mywiki/rpc/soap-axis/confluenceservice-v1?wsdl</url>
 </urls>

 <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-wsdl-sources</outputDirectory>
 <packageSpace>de.allianz.wsdl.confluence</packageSpace>
 <testCases>false</testCases>
 <serverSide>false</serverSide>
 <subPackageByFileName>false</subPackageByFileName>
</configuration>
<executions>
 <execution>
  <id>add wsdl source</id>
  <phase>generate-sources</phase>
  <goals>
   <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
  </goals>
 </execution>
</executions>
<dependencies>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>axis</groupId>
  <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
  <version>1.4</version>
 </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

If I use the following properties before the connect - everything works fine, but I set the properties VM wide which is not desirable:

```
 public void setProxyHost(String proxyHost) {
  this.proxyHost = proxyHost;
  if(proxyHost != null){
   System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", proxyHost);
   AxisProperties.setProperty("http.proxyHost", proxyHost);  

  }  
 }

 public void setProxyPort(int proxyPort) {
  this.proxyPort = proxyPort;
  System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", ""+proxyPort);
  AxisProperties.setProperty("http.proxyPort", ""+proxyPort);  
 }
```

Is there any way to tell axis to generate sources to connect through a proxy? (I already read about how th specify a proxy when generating the sources (to access the WSDL) but this is not what I need - I need to connect to the final webservice through a proxy)

I already tried to do the following:

```
private ConfluenceSoapService createConfluenceSoapService()
   throws ServiceException {
  ConfluenceSoapServiceServiceLocator csssl = new ConfluenceSoapServiceServiceLocator();
  ConfluenceSoapService confluenceSoapService;
  if (confluenceserviceAddress == null) {
   confluenceSoapService = csssl.getConfluenceserviceV1();
  } else {
   URL endpoint;
   try {
    //endpoint = new URL(confluenceserviceAddress);
    endpoint = new URL("http",proxyHost,proxyPort,confluenceserviceAddress);
   } catch (java.net.MalformedURLException e) {
    throw new javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException(e);
   }
   confluenceSoapService = csssl.getConfluenceserviceV1(endpoint);
  }
  ConfluenceserviceV1SoapBindingStub stub = (ConfluenceserviceV1SoapBindingStub) confluenceSoapService;
  stub.setTimeout(timeout);
  return confluenceSoapService;
 }
```

and change the endpoint to an URL using a proxy - but this leads to the following problem at runtime (even though the proxy settings are set correctly to the URL object. If I use the URL object without the proxy, I get to errors.

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: For input string: "8080http:"
 at org.apache.axis.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:101)
 at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:154)
 at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
 at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
 at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
 at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
 at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
 at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
```

**My Questions:**
- Am I missing something? 
- Is there a way to tell axis to generate the sources to work with a web proxy (to be accessed through a web proxy)

Thanks a lot for your help! Please let me know if you need more/other information to help.

Answer (score 5):

Try this, in my case it works, it is not a good idea to use System.setProperty as it sets the value for VM. Using AxisProperties will set the value only for specific connection. I am using AXIS 1.4 client.

```
AxisProperties.getProperties().put("proxySet","true");

    AxisProperties.setProperty("http.proxyHost", PROXY_HOST); 
    AxisProperties.setProperty("http.proxyPort", PROXY_PORT);
```

Comment: Doesn't this set the global AxisProperties? if you have other webservice calls, this would interefere with those